# what is the functionality of trace()?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

In the following example can I please know what does trace() do

```
var reportXML:XML = <Report>
                        <prop1>4</prop1>                      
                        <prop2>2255</prop2>
                        <prop3>true</prop3>
                        <prop4>false</prop4>
                    </Report>;
var myArray:Array = [{xmlNodeName: "prop5", value: false}];
for each (var item:Object in myArray) {
    reportXML[item.xmlNodeName] = item.value.toString();
}
trace(reportXML);
```

Comment: Please try to format your code so that it's readable.

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting. It is in pier review now. Below answer is correct. It is for debugger use.

Comment: your code output will be like : <Report>
  <prop1>4</prop1>
  <prop2>2255</prop2>
  <prop3>true</prop3>
  <prop4>false</prop4>
  <prop5>false</prop5>
</Report>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace will print to IDE console the String value of the reportXML variable.
The trace results are visible only when debugging the code.

Ex:

```
var strVal:String = "123";
var intVal:int    = 77;
var spriteObj:Sprite = new Sprite();


trace(strVal);
trace(intVal);
trace(spriteObj);

// will write to console:
// 123
// 77
// flash.display.Sprite (@2eccb01)
```

For the sprite is displayed the class signature and the memory address.

Answer (score 2):

When you call trace on an Object in Flash, the function does something like this internally.

```
trace(Object);


//pseudo implementation of trace 
function trace(obj:*)
{
    //open a socket connection at a previously decided port
    socket.open(xxxx);
    if(obj is String)
    {
        socket.write(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        socket.write(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

Your console window is something that listens to this socket. So when a stream is written to a socket, the console window shows it.

Some other external programs force the flash player to write this "log" to a file. Flash player has a way of enabling this. Once its getting written to a file, they "monitor" this file for any changes and print into their own consoles when the file changes.

Comment: nice answer. Can I have some reference link of well known sites where I can read the same and more

Comment: Unfortunately I cant provide any reference links which explain this. If Flash Player was open source I think it would have been easy to show this. I will see if I can dig up something. Vizzy tracer should be a start. Its a java program that "listens" to the trace statements that are emitted by Flash Player.

Answer (score 0):

It prints out the value of whatever you are tracing to the Output window within the Flash IDE.

It's used for debugging purposes.